# Linq GroupBy and Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Item

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using LINQ in C#

This code result in `dates` of type `Lookup<TKey, TElement>`

```
   var dates = timetableEvents.GroupBy(x => x.DateTimeStart);
```

I need instead just a list of DateTimeStart (of type DateTime).

How should I change my LINQ expressions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use `Select` instead:

```
var dates = timetableEvents.Select(x => x.DateTimeStart);
```

Or if you just want one from each group:

```
var dates = timetableEvents.GroupBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).Select(x => x.Key);
```

And if you want it to run a little bit faster, then you can use Distinct (as in Rawling's answer), but you probably won't notice much difference, unless you have a lot objects (though, the intention is much cleaner):

```
var dates = timetableEvents.Select(x => x.DateTimeStart).Distinct();
```

I find [this site](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) very useful when trying to learn LINQ: [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: Thanks Mario, but I need use GroupBy before... as timetable events must be grouped before

Comment: @GibboK `timetableEvents.GroupBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).Select(g=>g.Key)`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the start date/times,

```
var dates = timetableEvents.Select(x => x.DateTimeStart).Distinct();
```

may be more efficient than

```
var dates = timetableEvents.GroupBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).Select(x => x.Key);
```

as it knows it doesn't have to bother grouping the events together.

Comment: Distinct would work, except, your first line won't compile ;) Distinct takes either no parameter or the overload with `IEqualityComparer<T>` parameter.

Comment: Interesting use of Distinct()